# SKAction to Change AnchorPoint?

Tags: ios, animation, rotation, sprite-kit, anchorpoint

I am creating a relatively complicated animation sequence. In it, a certain `SKSpriteNode` (shark) does two rotations. At the beginning of the animation, it rotates around a certain anchor point *ap1*, then later rotates around a *different* anchor point *ap2*. How should I change anchor points midway through an animation sequence?

**Some initial thoughts:**

I could change the anchor point *outside* of `SKAction`s, in the `update:` loop perhaps.

I could use multiple `SKSpriteNode`s for the same shark sprite (with their respective anchor points), switching (hiding/showing) the sprite nodes when I need to change the anchor point.

Comment: you could use SKAction runBlock in the middle of a sequence

Comment: What does "switching (hiding/showing) the sprite nodes" mean?

Comment: It just means that I could change SKSpriteNodes midway through the animation. i.e. Hide Sprite 1, show Sprite 2.

Comment: Have you seen a sprite jump when you change its anchor point?

Comment: You can change the anchor point and position at the same time to not have a jump (in theory). I have done this while also changing the sprite texture and there's no jump. There is however a pause when the texture changes.

Comment: Are you pre-loading/reusing the textures? If you're using `imageNamed` to change the texture, I would expect a delay.

Comment: I am preloading the textures (some through atlases some through textures).

Answer (score 1):

Since changing a sprite's anchor point affects where it's rendered, you will likely need to make some sort of adjustment to prevent the sprite from appearing to suddenly move to a new location. Here's one way to do that:

Create action that changes the anchor point

```
    SKAction *changeAnchorPoint = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        [self updatePosition:sprite withAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    }];

    SKAction *rotate = [SKAction rotateByAngle:2*M_PI duration: 2];
```

Run action to rotate, change the anchor point, and rotate

```
    [sprite runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[rotate,changeAnchorPoint,rotate]] completion:^{
        // Restore the anchor point
        [self updatePosition:sprite withAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)];
    }];
```

This method adjusts a sprite's position to compensate for the anchor point change

```
- (void) updatePosition:(SKSpriteNode *)node withAnchorPoint:(CGPoint)anchorPoint
{
    CGFloat dx = (anchorPoint.x - node.anchorPoint.x) * node.size.width;
    CGFloat dy = (anchorPoint.y - node.anchorPoint.y) * node.size.height;
    node.position = CGPointMake(node.position.x+dx, node.position.y+dy);
    node.anchorPoint = anchorPoint;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Julio Montoya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/848098/julio-montoya) said, the easiest way to do this is to just "translate" code into an `SKAction` with the method `[SKAction runBlock:myBlock]`.